# Android Material Design AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I am new to Android Material Design Concept. I have created a new project and added material theme with AppCompat support for pre-lollipop versions but my problem is, in Lollipop it shows the ActionBar aka Toolbar but if i run the same in pre-lollipop it doesn't show the ActionBar.

Do i just need to use Toolbar control everywhere in my Layout regardless of API version?

**Edited:**

```
<!-- Base application theme for prelollipop -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>

<!-- Material theme for lollipop-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterialEverywhere   look over that one.

Comment: Post your layout, your style and your code

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti Not a big deal. it was just a default project to play around with material theme, as a check before i implement into my actual App. Question is Edited for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Activity needs to extend ActionBarActivity. AppCompat doesn't use the native Toolbar or ActionBar, even on Lollipop.

For more info see: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated.   Use {@link android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity} instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your activity must extend `ActionBarActivity`. You can ditch the special v21 style.

If your style extends `Theme.AppCompat` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light` there should be a default action bar automatically. If the style extends `...NoActionBar` you have to specify it in the layout like in pure `LOLLIPOP`. The second will give you finer control over the Toolbar theming.

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated.   Use {@link android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity} instead.

Answer (score -1):

try This

```
<style name="FamilyDashboardTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/familycolor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/familydarkcolor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/familycolor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```